# XSLT - sneaky insertion(xsl:copy)

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, stax

I will start with codes - we all like codes :D

XML:

```
    <report>
        <subject>
            <subjectId>1</subjectId>
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Doe</surname>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <subjectId>2</subjectId>
            <name>Frank</name>
            <surname>Timothy</surname>
        </subject>
        <individual>
            <individualId>10</individualId>
            <name>Isaac</name>
            <surname>Newton</surname>
            <co-worker>
                <subject>
                    <subjectId>1</subjectId>
                    <inXml>true</inXml>
                </subject>
                <subject>
                    <subjectId>2</subjectId>
                    <inXml>true</inXml>
                </subject>
            </co-worker>
        </individual>

        <owner>
            <subject>
                <subjectId>2</subjectId>
                <inXml>true</inXml>
            </subject>
            <share>100</share>
        </owner>

        <individual>
            <individualId>10</individualId>
            <inXml>true</inXml>
        </individual>
    </report>
```

XML 2:

```
    <report>
        <owner>
            <individual>
                <individualId>10</individualId>
                <inXml>true</inXml>
            </individual>
        </owner>
        <individual>
            <individualId>2</individualId>
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Doe</surname>
            <co-worker>
                <individual>
                    <individualId>10</individualId>
                    <inXml>true</inXml>
                </individual>
            </co-worker>
        </individual>
        <individual>
            <individualId>10</individualId>
            <name>Isaac</name>
            <surname>Newton</surname>
            <co-worker>
                <individual>
                    <individualId>2</individualId>
                    <inXml>true</inXml>
                </individual>
            </co-worker>
        </individual>

    </report>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:template match="individual[inXml='true']">
            <xsl:variable name="indId" select="./individualId/text()" />
            <xsl:variable name="result" select="//individual[not(inXml) and individualId=$indId]/*" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$result != ''">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$result" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="subject[inXml='true']">
            <xsl:variable name="subId" select="./subjectId/text()" />
            <xsl:variable name="result" select="//subject[not(inXml) and subjectId=$subId]/*" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$result != ''">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$result" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am tryin to achieve? - I want to copy subject / individual in a place where "inXml" tag appears. XSLT seems to work..but for slightly bigger xmls.. around 1MB (it's not big..)
my java application fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
I redirected stream to file..and surprisingly - the file with result of transformation was growing with speed of light - after 15sec around 300mb! :D hehehe - which proves there must be some error in my xlst which results in infinite loop.

What is important - while copying of nodes it may happen that there is already "inXml" inside - that's why i am applying template or result. XML that i prepared is depicting the problem.

EDIT: 
XML2 is very possible to totally mess up my application. How can I solve it? I was hoping to fix my jaxb unmarshalling problem by XSLT - that's not the solution i know - I need to insert reference of object during unmarshalling process instead of tryin insertion of more XML nodes there. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The xml and xsl in your post works for me running with xsltproc.

Comment: like i've said..it works in small file. in big ones it collapses ;-/

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete file where the transformation fails. Have you tried to increase the memory allowed for allocation by the Java JRE? Which Java XSLT processor do you use? If the data structure is recursive and the apply-templates is called again and again then I also would expect a stack overflow, not necessarily a out of memory error. When you transform to a file where you see the result growing, have you aborted the transformation or did it finish after some time?

Comment: it doesnt finish. after "couple of seconds" i stopped app with my file over 2gb big moment ago :D i am so proud of myself.. ]:>

Answer (score 0):

Your code will go into infinite recursion if there is a cycle in your data.

I suspect that the condition `not(inXml)` should be `not(inXML='true')` to prevent this; but not knowing your data, I can't be sure.

Comment: thanks for answer. not(inXml) is a condition from schema - either there is "full data + id" or  "inXml + id" - not(inXml='true') will slow the process down.

Comment: I think XML2 is depicting the circulation that may occure in my file. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @MironBe, When I have time I will try to find an acceptable solution. It is obvious that XSLT 2.0 is a better tool for solving this task, as it makes it possible not to use temporary document trees for the intermediate results and this translates in significant efficiency improvement -- both in memory and in time. Just making a "utility" transformation to check for cycles is much easier -- are you interested in such a utility and in an XSLT 2.0 solution?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, thank you for answer. I need to map XML to object in java. I thought XSLT will be a solution for me when i get "empty" objects with only inXml flag set. I am not sure if XSLT is what I really need now. I reckon I need to do more research on JAXB and find out how to solve it on that level.

Comment: @MironBe, XSLT is a good match to such kind of problems. What do you mean by "empty objects"? An example? It would be a good idea to edit the question and provide any such additional information.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, During unmarshalling process of node individualId=10 (with ALL data and inXml not existng), and further call of individual->getCoWorkerNo1()->getName() (very simplified way..but I just wanted to show what I have on my mind) will result in null value. Which is wrong ofc.

Comment: @MironBe, Yes, in this case this isn't an XSLT/XML problem. Glad you found the cause of the problem.